# How to call aws codedeploy endpoints using curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to list all deployments from aws codedeploy.  There's an aws codedeploy API here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/APIReference/API_ListDeployments.html but I'm still not sure how I would go about getting a response via curl.

I've tried this so far and it doesn't work:

```
echo $(curl -s 'https://ID_GOES_HERE.execute-api.LOCATION_GOES_HERE.amazonaws.com/ListDeployments')
```

EDIT:  I was able to get what I wanted to achieve by using boto3 for my python script.  I was originally planning to use requests:http to basically use GET calls but it seems like boto3 takes care of this for me.

Comment: Why do you need to use curl, rather than the AWS CLI itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you putting ID and Location in curl command ?Above mentioned command dont have id and location.

Also optionally you can try following CLI command to List the deployments in a deployment group for an application registered with the applicable IAM user or AWS account.

```
list-deployments
[--application-name <value>]
[--deployment-group-name <value>]
[--include-only-statuses <value>]
[--create-time-range <value>]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--starting-token <value>]
[--max-items <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```